# How to scrollToEnd in reverse direction in react native flatList ? On new chat arrives

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I've flatList with inverted property true along with onContentSizeChange scrollToEnd problem is whenever new chat arrives the scroll to end scroll flatList to top instead of bottom I've searched everywhere the solution but found nothing

```js
      <FlatList
        ref={flatlistThreadListRef}
        data={displayThread}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <>
            {currentUserId === item.sender._id ? (
              <RightChatBubble displayThread={item} />
            ) : (
              <LeftChatBubble displayThread={item} />
            )}
          </>
        )}
        style={{ height: responsiveWidth(172) }}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
        onContentSizeChange={() =>
          flatlistThreadListRef?.current?.scrollToEnd()
        }
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        inverted={displayThread.length !== 0}
        
      />
```

I want that whenever new chat either image with text, single image or single text arrive it automatically scroll to bottom, please help how do I implement this

I tried passing inverting

```js
  data={displayThread.reverse()}
```

insteadd inverted property but not worked it was not smooth